# Is there a way in java that interface can deliver function with already implemented part of code?

Tags: java

Is there a way in java that interface can deliver function with already implemented part of code? e.g.

```java
//somewhere in java classes
void function1(){
  MyClient client = MyClient.getNew();
  if(client.isReal()){
    // function2 is an expansion for function1
  }
}

//someInterface.java
public interface someInterface{
  public void function2(MyClient client);
}

//someClass.java
public class someClass implements someInterface{
  @Override
  public void function2(MyClient client){
    client.send("Hi!");
  }
}
```

Maybe I didn't make it clear. I want to make an interface that delivers a function. No problem. But this function must implement some logic checks. How can I do that?

Comment: yes, its called [default method](https://jaxenter.de/java-tutorial-java-8-methoden-in-interfaces-1359), put keyword `default` in front of the method, and you can add its body with the code.

Comment: I think you're looking for [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. It looks like the whole function is skipped.

Comment: @Hazaki please prefix your comments with a "@" and the name of the user you're responding to (like I just did), so it's clear who you're responding to

Comment: Ah okay. It was to @NikolaiDmitriev

Comment: Oops. It looks like the function is not skipped but the results are not satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You have to write a default method in your interface. Please go through this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) to find more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. It looks like the whole function I wrote is skipped

Comment: Oops. It looks like the function is not skipped but the results are not satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has introduced the notion of "[default methods"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), so you can definitively implement a method on an interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. It looks like the whole function I wrote is skipped

Comment: Oops. It looks like the function is not skipped but the results are not satisfying.